# Monogame (VB) .mgfx effect was built for a different platform

Tags: vb.net, monogame, effect

I am trying to impliment a guassian blur into my game and I keep getting this error when I try to import it into my project. Here is the code I used to define the effect:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("Content\Effects\effects.mgfxo")
Dim effect As Effect = New Effect(Game.graphics.GraphicsDevice, bytes)
```

Somewhere in the code for the .fx file do I need to specify the platform before converting it to a .mgtx? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about mgfxo files but maybe [this post on the MonoGame forums](http://community.monogame.net/t/how-to-import-mgfxo-effects-file-to-project-solved/412) will lead you in the right direction. If you do discover the answer there, please post the answer back here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

After much confusion, I finally came upon my answer (somewhat). The issue lied in the code inside the .fx file. This code ran without crashing on my windows 10 PC:

PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 PS_GaussianBlur();

After I changed the code, I used the monogame pipeline tool to convert it to an xnb file and plopped it into my content/Effects folder. I then used this code to directly run it:

Dim effect As Effect = content.Load(Of Effect)("Effects\GaussianBlur")

With all that said and done, the Gaussian blur effect does not occur. Whenever I try to do this, the output texture2D is only a solid color (color depending on what was in the top left corner of the original image). If anyone knows how to fix it than id greatly appreciate it, although I will be setting up a new question for that and give more detail.